# CakePHP v2 model local variables

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on moving to CakePHP v2 from v1.3.

In my old 1.3 model I had some local variables which a loadData() function set, and then I could retrieve using a get function.

In v2 I get:

```
Indirect modification of overloaded property [...] has no effect
```

I've searched but it isn't related to the data/request->data changes.

Any ideas on how to set these local variables?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should post the relevant code here, as wel. also, which 2.x version you are using.

Comment: You're right, my bad.

After the model properties (hasOne etc), I've got:
  var $acntarr = array();

And in the one function I:
  $this->acntarr[$ww]['global']['total'] = $rescnt;

Comment: it should be "public $acntarr = array()"

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it still gives the:
Indirect modification of overloaded property ::$acntarr has no effect

Should I change the way I access it in the function?

Comment: You should post the code of `loadData()` here

Comment: It's just a simple find(...) and I load the data into some local arrays, there are a few more similar functions that populate these arrays and I wanted to be able to migrate the whole model over and still use these "local" variables.

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting code into comments!

Comment: "Indirect modification of overloaded property **>what's this<** has no effect" where's the code where you manipulate **>what's this<** - your question is missing all info to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you updated any code that you are trying to assign values to the $this->data array
to $this->request->data ?

You can no longer assign manually $this->data['newthing']['here'] any more in 2.0

It must be $this->request->data['newthing']['here'] or unset $this->request->data['currentthing']['here'] etc etc

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/Sa-2m95CezM

Like the others said, however, some code would be nice if you have the time.  Thanks.